# Do I need to use a mutex in Android Content-Provider methods?

Tags: android, thread-safety, mutex, android-contentprovider

I'm making my own content-provider. In the documentation for the content-provider it says the methods like query, insert, and update need to be thread safe. So should I guard them with a mutex like so?

```
private static Mutex cpMutex;

public Cursor query(){
  cpMutex.lock();
  //do stuff
  cpMutex.unlock();
  return result;
}

public Uri insert(){
  cpMutex.lock();
  //do stuff
  cpMutex.unlock();
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably shouldn't use synching, you should just do thread safe operations. What are you doing that's not thread safe?

Comment: Manipulating the backend  data stucture for which the content provider is a frontend. I'm pretty sure I'm going to use a sqllite database. Will it take care f the synchronization for me?

Comment: I don't know what the hacienda data structure is. But the SQL class is thread safe.

Comment: Sorry about that. I meant backend. Autocorrect is damaging sometimes. :) But good to know SQL is threadsafe.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use mutex. Just make the methods synchronized. Like so:

```
public synchronized Cursor query(){
...
}
```

Comment: Yea, I guess this would work as long as I didn't run the methods on the UI thread, which doesn't seem very good in terms of programming practice. Then again, the same things goes for my original idea of using mutex's (D'oh!). I think Falmarri's response is probably the correct path.